# Native code programming technique in a vb6 class module

Tags: class, module, vb6, native-code

I would like to implement this particular programming technique in my vb6 class, but I cannot understand how the "Nativecode" lines were obtained. Are these normal lines of code, obfuscated by some particular software?
Is it possible to get the original code through reverse engineering?
Could anyone tell me where I can find useful documentation about it?
Thanks for any replies.

[image]

The code snippet comes from a series of classes, written in VB6, provided by the VBMapi program. These classes, inserted in a VB6 application designed for sending many emails, allow you to bypass the constant outlook warning messages.

In what way and with which compiler we get that native code to paste in a vb class and allocate directly in memory?

Comment: Looks like it could be Ascii85 (aka Base85) encoded.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85 for info on that encoding.  As to how it got that way, I'd guess someone had a com program (.com extension), wrote some code (or used a tool like btoa) to read it in and output the encoded value string. If so, you could un-encode it, leaving the binary executable (more or less), then run it through available tools to see if you can get assembler, c code, or something else that might make sense.

Comment: @MarkL by COM it probably means https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model which is widely used with VB6

Comment: @StayOnTarget, I don't believe that comment about COM is referencing the COM link you point out.  Code in the pic appears to be loading the string into memory, making api calls to obtain process handles and addresses. Next steps below where the picture cuts off could be to try and execute that loaded string data. Thus COM as in the old style self contained executable program. I could be wrong - I have not searched for a source of where OP obtained this code snippet, nor looked up the api calls being made above.

Comment: @MarkL you may well be right; I was mainly going off the comment which used the term "COM object". But that could be misleading, most of the code below that is missing.  I had thought this might have been an in-memory image of an actual object - but maybe that is too bizarre.

Comment: The code snippet comes from a series of classes, written in VB6, provided by the VBMapi program. These classes, inserted in a VB6 application designed for sending many emails, allow you to bypass the constant outlook warning messages.

Comment: From this link (https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-rename-picture-files-based-on-date-taken.1156366/  Search for `NativeCode`), it appears they are simply alloc'ing a memory block as executable, casting that memory ref as an object, and then calling it directly as executable code...  That said, it's not a technique I'm familiar with, but they seem to be creating actual machine-level code in those strings and executing it directly...  This would make it hard for most people to even know what the code does (virus?), but I suppose it might be useful in certain situtations?

Comment: So the final unsolved question is: in what way and with which compiler we get that native code to paste in a vb class and allocate directly in memory?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/19239/compilers-demystified-function-pointers-in-visual

Take a look at this link...  I think this is what they're doing.  As the article states, wrt the last question:  "You can use any assembler to produce native code from the above. I have written it as a Visual C++ __asm block and then copied the native code produced from the disassembly view."  I don't know if this is done as ASM, or compile code as another language and then grabbing the literal "native code", but that's what it looks like.

Comment: @user51 thanks for your valuable contribution. The link you have posted is really very interesting.